# How to increment the variable names created jlabels using for loop?

Tags: java, loops, netbeans, jlabel, increment

java code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10;++i) {
   if (i == 9){
     lbl_ichar.setText(String.valueOf(word.charAt(i)));
   }
}
```

This code shows error message(compile time error:cannot find symbol
 symbol: variable class lbl_ichar) under word `lbl_ichar`.But I have already created jlabels of variable names `lbl_0char`,`lbl_1char`,`lbl_2char`...... upto `lbl_9char`.

I want to call by the name `lbl_ichar` instead of using `lbl_9char`.Is that possible in java? If so how to code it?

Comment: What do you mean by "this code shows error message"? Do you get compiler errors? Wrong text in the label? Something else? Please elaborate, and *include* the actual error (in full, complete and unedited).

Comment: yes compile time erroe

Comment: Mind telling us **which** compile time error?

Comment: what is `word` in your code?

Comment: I can assure that there's no problem with word

Comment: May be,can you at least tell me its length?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**try to do something likewise,**

**JLabel lb_char[] = new JLable[10];**

*then after into Loop you can refer that labels like this way,*

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10;++i) {

     lbl_char[i].setText(String.valueOf(word.charAt(i)));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are trying to create a variable name dynamically at runtime:

```
JLabel lbl_1char = new JLabel();
JLabel lbl_2char = new JLabel();
// ...

for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
   lbl_ichar.setText(String.valueOf(word.charAt(i)));
   //  ^
}
```

This does not work. You can not create the variable name at runtime. Use an array instead:

```
JLabel[] lbl_char = new JLabel[10];
lbl_char[0] = new JLabel();
lbl_char[1] = new JLabel();
// ...

for (int i = 0; i < lbl_char.length; i++) {
   lbl_char[i].setText(String.valueOf(word.charAt(i)));
}
```

Or, even better, instead of using raw arrays, use an `ArrayList`:

```
List<JLabel> lbl_char = new ArrayList<>();
lbl_char.add(new JLabel());
lbl_char.add(new JLabel());
// ...

for (JLabel lbl : lbl_char) {
   lbl.setText("Whatever");
}
```

Comment: Yep, use a label array or access the labels via reflection.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly use loop variable i value like "lbl_ichar".

you want to change the value only if your i value is 9, or do you want to set new value for "lbl_9char" ?